# Inflating a layout to get resource (views) IDs

Tags: android, layout-inflater

```
Android Studio 0.5.2
```

Hello,

I have a preference screen that that has a custom preference layout, as I wanted to add a seekbar for a
sensitivity selection in the settings.

However, I can't seem to find away to get the view id (mSbrSensitivity - seekbar) to set the ChangeListener as its null.

I don't want to use `setContentView(R.layout.custom_prefs)` as this will display the UI, and when I make the call to `addPreferenceFromResource(R.xml.prefs)` it will display the layout again as in preference screen I have this set to my `custom_prefs` layout.

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    private SeekBar mSbrSensitivity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_prefs, null);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);

        /* Get views */
        mSbrSensitivity = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.sbSensitivity); // Returns NULL

        /* Set listeners */
        mSbrSensitivity.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    /* More stuff here */
}
```

My preference screen:

```
<PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:key="custom_prefs_key">
    <Preference
        android:key="SensorKey"
        android:title="Sensitivity"
        android:summary="Adjust how sentivitive you are"
        android:layout="@layout/custom_prefs"> <!-- Load custom prefs layout -->
    </Preference>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

And my custom preference layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/sbSensitivity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tvDisplay"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDisplay"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sbSensitivity">
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_prefs, null);   mSbrSensitivity = (SeekBar)v.findViewById(R.id.sbSensitivity); tried this?

Comment: @playmaker420, Yes, that did work. I guess getting the layout view using the inflater and then getting the views on that layout using v.findViewByID worked. However, It seems I need to call setContentView and all I had to do was remove this line of code from my xml android:layout="@layout/custom_prefs". Everything seemed to work after that.